# How to perform calculation in spark dataframe that select from its own dataframe using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark schema which look like this :

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- long: float (nullable = true)
 |-- lat: float (nullable = true)
 |-- geohash: string (nullable = true)
 |-- neighbors: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

The data look like this :

```
+---+---------+----------+---------+--------------------+
| id|      lat|      long|geohash_8|           neighbors|
+---+---------+----------+---------+--------------------+
|  0|-6.361755| 106.79653| qqggy1yu|[qqggy1ys, qqggy1...|
|  1|-6.358584|106.793945| qqggy4ky|[qqggy4kw, qqggy4...|
|  2|-6.362967|106.798775| qqggy38m|[qqggy38j, qqggy3...|
|  3|-6.358316| 106.79832| qqggy680|[qqggy4xb, qqggy6...|
|  4| -6.36016|  106.7981| qqggy60j|[qqggy4pv, qqggy6...|
|  5|-6.357476| 106.79842| qqggy68j|[qqggy4xv, qqggy6...|
|  6|-6.360814| 106.79435| qqggy4j3|[qqggy4j1, qqggy4...|
|  7|-6.358231|106.794365| qqggy4t2|[qqggy4t0, qqggy4...|
|  8|-6.357654| 106.79736| qqggy4x7|[qqggy4x5, qqggy4...|
|  9|-6.358781|106.794624| qqggy4mm|[qqggy4mj, qqggy4...|
| 10|-6.357654| 106.79443| qqggy4t7|[qqggy4t5, qqggy4...|
| 11|-6.357079| 106.79443| qqggy4tr|[qqggy4tp, qqggy4...|
| 12|-6.359929| 106.79698| qqggy4pn|[qqggy4ny, qqggy4...|
| 13|-6.358111| 106.79633| qqggy4w9|[qqggy4w3, qqggy4...|
| 14|-6.359685| 106.79607| qqggy4q8|[qqggy4q2, qqggy4...|
| 15|-6.357945|106.794945| qqggy4td|[qqggy4t6, qqggy4...|
| 16|-6.360725|106.795456| qqggy4n4|[qqggy4jf, qqggy4...|
| 17|-6.363701| 106.79653| qqggy1wb|[qqggy1w8, qqggy1...|
| 18| -6.36329|106.794586| qqggy1t7|[qqggy1t5, qqggy1...|
| 19|-6.363304| 106.79429| qqggy1t5|[qqggy1sg, qqggy1...|
+---+---------+----------+---------+--------------------+
```

I want to calculate the distance from each id with its lat long and select all the lat long from all his neighbors then calculate the distance. Then every id will have list of distances in meters with all his neighbors.

I tried using iterative way, which loop every rows then select a dataframe then compute the haversine distance, However the performance is awful. I am stuck on how to apply using functional way in spark. Can anyone help with some suggestion or references.

Comment: Cross joining the data frame with itself and then filtering on the basis of neighbors column of left df contains the geohash_8 obtained from right df shall give all the neighbor combinations.

Then the function which you were using in loop and can be applied without looping.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Cross join will works but it will generate massive data in the result before filterig. Because my source table have more than 160M rows, it will take a long time. I used Ryan ways of exploding and joining, however I need the distance pair to be combinations. For example id 0 have neighbors (2,3,4), then i need to calc the distance for [(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: Won't it happen any way?
The `id=0` shall contain 3 neighbors i.e. `2,3,4`. After exploding this would transform to 3 rows with `id=0` and neighbor as 2, 3, and 4 in different rows. Similarly, `id=2` shall have 3 rows with 0, 3, and 4 in neighbor column.
All you need to do is remove duplicate combinations by making a sorted set and then doing remove duplicates. You can calculate distance after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated to address desire for combinations**

If you want to do all the combinations, the steps are basically, associate each neighbor ID with it's lat/long, group them together into a single row for each combination set, then do compute distance on all the combinations.  Here is example code:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
import itertools

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType()),
    StructField("lat", FloatType()),
    StructField("long", FloatType()),
    StructField("geohash_8", StringType()),
    StructField("neighbors", ArrayType(StringType()))
])

data = [
     ("0", 10.0, 11.0, "A", ["B", "C", "D"]),
     ("1", 12.0, 13.0, "B", ["D"]),
     ("2", 14.0, 15.0, "C", []),
     ("3", 16.0, 17.0, "D", [])
]

input_df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(data), schema)

# Explode to get a row for each comparison pair
df = input_df.withColumn('neighbor', explode('neighbors')).drop('neighbors')

# Join to get the lat/lon of the neighbor
neighbor_map = input_df.selectExpr('geohash_8 as nid', 'lat as nlat', 'long as nlong')
df = df.join(neighbor_map , col('neighbor') == col('nid'), 'inner').drop('nid')

# Add in rows for the root (geohash_8) records before grouping
root_rows = input_df.selectExpr("id", "lat", "long", "geohash_8", "geohash_8 as neighbor", "lat as nlat", "long as nlong")
df = df.unionAll(root_rows)

# Group by to roll the rows back up but now associating the lat/lon w/ the neighbors
df = df.selectExpr("id", "lat", "long", "geohash_8", "struct(neighbor, nlat, nlong) as neighbors")
df = df.groupBy("id", "lat", "long", "geohash_8").agg(collect_set("neighbors").alias("neighbors"))

# You now have all the data you need in one field, so you can write a python udf to do the combinations
def compute_distance(left_lat, left_lon, right_lat, right_lon):
    return 10.0

def combinations(neighbors):
    result = []
    for left, right in itertools.combinations(neighbors, 2):
        dist = compute_distance(left['nlat'], left['nlong'], right['nlat'], right['nlong'])
        result.append(Row(left=left['neighbor'], right=right['neighbor'], dist=dist))
    return result

udf_schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("left", StringType()),
    StructField("right", StringType()),
    StructField("dist", FloatType())
]))
combinations_udf = udf(combinations, udf_schema)

# Finally, apply the UDF
df = df.withColumn('neighbors', combinations_udf(col('neighbors')))
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

Which produces this:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lat: float (nullable = true)
 |-- long: float (nullable = true)
 |-- geohash_8: string (nullable = true)
 |-- neighbors: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- neighbor: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- nlat: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- nlong: float (nullable = true)

+---+----+----+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |lat |long|geohash_8|neighbors                                                                           |
+---+----+----+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0  |10.0|11.0|A        |[[D, C, 10.0], [D, A, 10.0], [D, B, 10.0], [C, A, 10.0], [C, B, 10.0], [A, B, 10.0]]|
|2  |14.0|15.0|C        |[]                                                                                  |
|1  |12.0|13.0|B        |[[D, B, 10.0]]                                                                      |
|3  |16.0|17.0|D        |[]                                                                                  |
+---+----+----+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. This is awesome, but I need the pair to be combinations, for example id 0 have neighbors (2,3,4) then the distance pair that need to be calculated should be [(0,2), (0,3), (0,4), (2,3),(2,4), (3,4)], do you have any idea ? I was thinking group by the source id and lat long then apply the itertools.combination function with distance calculation.

Comment: Updated with a complete example that I think does what you are looking for.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that you can return such complex schema in spark. I am still learning it. you are lifesaving man. I learned a lot from your code.Thank you so much. Have a nice day.